# How to get international dialing code on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know i can get the country code with NSLocaleCountryCode but I'm
looking for the numerical equivalent to generate an internationnal phone
number.

I need 01 instead of US.

I can of course use my own table but I'm guessing there is already an API
for that but I can't find it.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/mledoze/countries) you can download all in JSON, XML and CVS format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no such thing in the iPhone SDK.

Comment: I did not find anything and ended up using my own code and dialing code database.